# Emacs 24.4 custom themes

Tags: macos, emacs, themes

I recently installed Emacs 24 on my Mac using Homebrew (I used to use Aquamacs for some time but I want to familiarize myself more with LISP and what Emacs has to offer and thus would prefer GNU Emacs in the future).

I have some problems using customized themes though. I downloaded zenburn and solarized using the emacs package manager. Packages were automatically saved to

```
 .emacs.d/elpa/solarized-theme-20150326.2320
 .emacs.d/elpa/zenburn-theme-20150315.1540
```

When I go to "Options>Customize Emacs>Custom Themes" both themes are displayed. When I tick one of the themes, it gets properly changed and displayed but I am unable to change the settings. If I save, the following gets written to my .emacs file:

```
(custom-set-variables
'(custom-enabled-themes (quote (solarized-dark)))
'(custom-safe-themes
(quote ("8aebf25556399b58091e533e455dd50a6a9cba958cc4ebb0aab175863c25b9a4"      "ed8fb2bc0f63c0fceffda864dedebc22b18edec238f7d52432f4af25a17a477a" "d677ef584c6dfc0697901a44b885cc18e206f05114c8a3b7fde674fce6180879" default))))
```

However, when I close and open Emacs again it states:

```
Failed to enable theme: solarized-dark
```

Any suggestions on what to do or what I am doing wrong?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out that adding to following lines to my .emacs file solves the issue:

```
(package-initialize)
```